# Can't delete duplicity s3/glacier archives

Tags: backup, duplicity

For backing up my system to s3, I'm running:

- duplicity 0.8.17
- Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
- boto3 '1.24.36'

My backups run fine, as desired they are moved from s3 to glacier after a month, duplicity status shows everything as it should, with monthly full backups and daily incrementals, going back 62 months, e.g.

```
Secondary chain 54 of 62:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Sun Oct 24 02:05:01 2021
Chain end time: Tue Nov 23 02:05:01 2021
Number of contained backup sets: 31
Total number of contained volumes: 8223
 Type of backup set:                            Time:   Number of volumes:
                Full         Sun Oct 24 02:05:01 2021              6450
         Incremental         Mon Oct 25 02:05:02 2021                64
```

But when I try to prune old incrementals

```
duplicity remove-all-inc-of-but-n-full 7 --force boto3+s3:///[bucket name]/
```

I get

```
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: none
No old backup sets found, nothing deleted.
```

I've searched and found nothing, but is it perhaps because the older archives are on glacier?  The metadata is all on s3 as it should be...

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the problem was omitting prexix and gpg options that were present in doing the backup.  Here's the command that *did* work:

```
  duplicity remove-all-inc-of-but-n-full \
    --file-prefix-manifest=m_ --file-prefix-archive=a_ --file-prefix-signature=s_ \
    --encrypt-key=xxx --sign-key=xxx \
     --force 7 boto3+s3:///markup.co.uk/
```

My only excuse is that those options were not necessary for the status command to work.